# Best word/phrase for peer-reviewing service

Tags: service-activities

I am a PC member and reviewer for a few conferences. I would like to list these services on my CV. However, I am not sure what would be a good title word for it?

**Community Service??**

**Academic Service??**

Just plain **Service** sound incomplete

Please suggest.

Comment: Other activities?

Comment: Naah.. It would have the word service in it. I just need to find an appropriate prefix word

Comment: I am referee or I serve as referee for "most prestigious journals here" as well as several other publications in the "field (s) here".

Comment: Referee service.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At my institution, the standard term is **professional service**, i.e. service to your profession.

"Community service" would be something like volunteering your skills for a local charity, so that doesn't fit.  "Academic service" seems reasonable but I haven't heard it before.

Comment: Agree with “professional service”, which is also standard where I am. It is considered as a subcategory of “service” (which would also include things like departmental and campus service), so “service” would also be an appropriate title - it isn’t incomplete and is understood by everyone who has been in academia for a while. Although I agree it sounds a bit funny (especially when incorrectly written as “services” by non-native English speakers).